# How to centerize overflowed container with padding?

Tags: css, overflow, padding

I need to centerize overflowed container (div or section) that has padding and it's inside of body.
Container is fixed width (500 pixels in example) and padding 100 pixels horizontally. How could I centerize this container?

I tried following:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 100px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/tu6yg5ch/

If you will change width of result tab less than 700 pixels, you would see that container isn't properly centerized.

Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one way of doing it.  You need to use positioning with either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`.

The type of positioning to use will depend on other aspects of the layout, for example,
if you have other elements after the wrapper, any fixed heights for the wrapper and
so on.

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 100px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    content
</div>
```

**Note:** The border-box property is not strictly necessary.  The `margin-left` value needs to be
half of the total width of the wrapper element, so you need to do the math right to the computed
width of the wrapper block.

Comment: Let's say, there's another block underneath #wrapper, footer. http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/tu6yg5ch/5/ That doesn't seem to work out, if this block would have fixed height, then I could use padding-top on body to shift blocks down. Thank you for your efforts, but this solution isn't the one I need. Can you think of something else?

Comment: That is correct, the absolute positioning takes the `#wrapper` out of the regular content flow.  You need make some design decision such as specify a height on the wrapper otherwise you will need some JavaScript or jQuery to compute heights or widths for you.

Comment: I changed `position: absolute` to `position: relative` and it worked out perfectly! http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/tu6yg5ch/6/

Comment: Could you change answer from `position: absolute` to `position: relative`, so people could see it, instead of looking into comments?

Comment: Well spotted about using `position: relative`, I overlooked that possibility.  In your case, it works nicely.  I expanded my answer accordingly.  Thank you for the help!